# wrong output with php dom

Tags: php, html, dom, utf-8

I have a simple rich utf-8 text like this:

```
$content = '<p> a simple <a href="http://unicode.com"> UTF-8</a> text.
                  <img src ="http://unicode.com/pic.jpeg" /></p>'
```

So I want to change src value with php dom:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
 $newsrc = 'http://unicode.com/pic.png';
foreach ($imgs as $img) 
{
     $img->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);
}
$content = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $content;
```

I except this output result:

```
<p> a simple <a href="http://unicode.com"> UTF-8</a> text.
                  <img src ="http://unicode.com/pic.png" /> </p>
```

But I get something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body>6;&#1585<p><a href="http://unicode.com">&#1608;&#1740; &#1662;&#1575;&#1585;&#1587;: </a>
&#1662;&#1575;&#1740;&#1711;&#1575;&#1607;
<img src="http://unicode.com/pic.png" /></p></body></html>
```

Now I do not want any extra tags like DOCTYPE,html,body,...
And I want normal char not like `&#1711`; and like that.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with PHP 5.4+.  Simply pass the [`LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`](https://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-nodefdtd) and [`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`](https://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-noimplied) flags to `DOMDocument::loadHTML`:

```
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
```

If PHP 5.4+ is not an option for you, see the [`DOMDocument::saveHTML` comments](https://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php#usernotes) for alternative solutions.

Comment: I use PHP 5.3 but the link works for me.thanks...but what about chars? how can I show that normally not like '&#1711;'

Comment: @aliraha: Those characters are not appearing for me, nor do they appear when [running the code here](http://3v4l.org/ofXbJ).

Comment: You are right. I wrote text in English to readable. actual text in utf-8 (persian lang.) is here: http://3v4l.org/odDaO#v540

Comment: @aliraha:  You should be able to run the HTML through the following function to convert the HTML entities back to UTF-8: `$content = mb_convert_encoding($doc->saveHTML(), 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');`